# Show that $X \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y \times X$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, product-space

This seems to be a trivial result, I just wish to check for correctness.

**Show $X \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y \times X$**

Let $\tau$ be the topology on $X$, $j$ be the topology on $Y$

Then a homeomorphism is given by $f: X \times Y \to Y \times X, (a,b) \to (b,a)$

We can show that $f$ is a homeomorphism by showing that it is continuous and open.

$f$ is continuous because given $B \times A$, $f^{-1}(B \times A) = A \times B$ is open in the product topology on $X \times Y$.

Similarly, we can show that $f$ is open in that $f(A \times B) = B \times A$ is open in the product topology on $Y \times X$

Therefore $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: The claim is correct. The proof is not (not complete at least), since not all open sets in the product topology can be written as products $A\times B$

Comment: An open subset of $X \times Y$ need not have the form $A \times B$, so you need to say more.

Comment: @RobArthan Take arbitrary $U$ in the product, then $U$ can be written as some union of $\{A \times B\}$, where $A$ is an open set in $X$ and $B$ is an open set in $Y$...I'm not sure how

Comment: That's the extra bit you have to add: $U$ is open in $X \times Y$ iff for every $u \in U$ there is an open subset $A$ of $X$ and an open subset $B$ of $Y$ such that $u \in A \times B$ and $A \times B \subseteq U$ ... now you can take over ...

Comment: @RobArthan, alternatively, one can use the fact that a function is continuous even if it is only known to pull back elements of a subbasis to open sets (but it sounds like this is coming fairly early on in learning topology, so perhaps it is good to avoid assuming this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it the idea is correct. Maybe one should add that on $X\times Y$ and $Y\times X$ we choose the product topology. The basis of such product topology is the collection $A\times B$ with $A$ and $B$ open in the respective spaces (or in the respective bases). In order to have continuity it is enough to check the "open set property" for the basis elements.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to only check for basis element